# Using DiagrammeR to place one rows of nodes below another

Tags: r, diagram, flowchart, mermaid

Given the following flow chart derived via `DiagrammeR` package:

```
DiagrammeR::DiagrammeR(diagram =
                       "
                       graph LR;
                       A[Start]-->B;
                       B --> C;
                       C --> D;
                       D --> E;
                       E --> F;
                       ")
```

[image: Sample Diagram]

Would it be possible to *wrap it* so the node **`E`** is below node **`D`** and node **`F`** follows to the left as in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: are you sworn to mermaid (which Im sure there will be a way to do it) or is graphviz an option

Comment: @user20650 yes, I think graphviz could be an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `graphviz` option.

For example, you can get the basic node positions of the graph using

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
  digraph flow {
       D -> E;
       {rank=same ; A -> B -> C -> D};
       {rank=same ;           F -> E[dir=back]};
   }
")
```

And you can add a few attributes to prettify it

```
grViz('
  digraph flow {

       # set characteristics 
       node[shape=square, 
            height=1,
            color=skyblue, 
            penwidth=2,
            fillcolor=lavender, 
            style=filled,
            fontsize=25, 
            fontcolor=grey46,
            fontname = "helvetica" # this may be OS dependent
            ];
       edge[minlen=2, 
            color=grey,
            penwidth=2
            ];
       nodesep=0.5; #hack
       A[label=Start];

       # Graph
       D -> E;
       {rank=same ; A -> B -> C -> D};
       {rank=same ;           F -> E[dir=back]};
  }
')
```

Which produces

[image]